# In Sql Server 2008,How to number shipments for each customer

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, row-number

I have two tables : Customer ------>> Shipment

I want to give each shipment a unique number for each customer, for example

```
CustomerID      ShipmentID       ShipmnetNumber
    10              50                  1
    10              51                  2
    10              55                  3

    15              56                  1
    15              57                  2
    15              58                  3

    17              59                  1
    17              60                  2
```

etc ...

how can I do it in sql server 2008

Comment: Are you talking about storing this `ShipmentNumber` column? If so there is no good way of doing this in SQL Server really. Inserts need to find out the current partition `Max` and block other concurrent inserts to the same partition etc.

Comment: Can't it be done even using (With statement ) ???

Comment: It can be done straight forwardly as a `SELECT` with `ROW_NUMBER` but the `ShipmentNumber` won't be stable over time if you ever have deletes. Please explain what you are trying to do here (the motivation)

Comment: Ok, I'm intending to store it, but how can I do that ?

Comment: The initial set up is straight forward as per Mikael's answer but keeping it up-to-date is a pain.

Comment: One strategy to handle generation of new shipment numbers could be to keep the last shipment number in customers table and increment that in the same transaction that you add a row to shipment. You should also have a unique constraint in shipment on customerid+shipmentnumber to make sure that any race condition ends with a failure/exception instead of duplicate shipment numbers for a customer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the numbering with a query you can do this

```
select CustomerID,
       ShipmentID,
       row_number() over(partition by Shipment.CustomerID  
                         order by ShipmentID) as ShipmentNumber
from Shipment
```

If you want to update a table with ShipmentNumber (newly added column) you can do this

```
;with S as
(
  select ShipmentNumber,
         row_number() over(partition by Shipment.CustomerID  
                           order by ShipmentID) as ShipNum
  from Shipment
)
update S
set ShipmentNumber = ShipNum
```